# Minhag to leave an area of the wall unpainted: does it need to be unpainted, or can it be painted another color?

Tags: halacha, minhag, color, home-house

I found this: http://www.jewishtreats.org/2014/07/a-house-unfinished.html it says "there are some minority opinions that permit one to mark the zeicher l’churban by painting an appropriate size square a different color than the rest of the wall." but it doesn't provide any sources.

My friend was painting his house and by mistake painted over part of the bare section and it is no longer an amah al amah.

Comment: At a synagogue I know, a part was left unpainted (instead of using a different colour)

Comment: @k Yes I think everyone agrees that leaving it unpainted is fine, the question is if painting it another color would also suffice.

Comment: I would then add that to the question

Answer (score 7):

[R. Mordechai Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe) mentions the custom of darkening one section of the wall as the zecher l'churban, but he says that this is not proper.

**Levush O.C. 560:1**

> ונ"ל מה שנוהגים עכשיו הבונים בתים ומסיידם אותו שמסיידין ומכיירין אותו
>   כולו ואחר כך משחירין אמה על אמה בשיחור כנגד הפתח דלא יפה הם עושין כי
>   אדרבה השיחור זה אינו מגנה את הבנין אבל מייפהו ומשמח הלב כשאר ציורים
>   הנאים וחז"ל אמרו משייר בו אמה על אמה כלומר שמניחו כך מקולקל ובלי מתוקן
>   כדי לגנות הבנין ולשבר לבו שמתוך כך יזכור החורבן ובשברון לב ולא שייפהו
>   ויזכור מתוך שמחת לב נ"ל

[R. Yechiel Michel Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein), however, justifies this custom.

**Aruch Hashulchan O.C. 560:5**

> וגדולי האחרונים כתבו דלא מהני מה שמשחירין אמה על אמה אלא דווקא להניח
>   ריק מסיד [שם סק"ג] ואצלינו משחירין וכיון דרגילין שזהו ההיכר לחורבן מה
>   לנו אם כה ואם כה

Additionally, [R. Elija Spira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Spira) notes that [R. Isaiah Horowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz) decried this practice, but he also notes that he found that [R. Alexander Suslin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Suslin) apparently endorsed this.

**Eliah Rabbah O.C. 560:4**

> בשל"ה קרא תגר על זה ואני מצאתי באגודה סוף תענית זה לשונו יניח בלא ציור
>   סיד או מראה שחור רק בלא תיקון כלל

Based on this, [R. Israel Meir Kagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Meir_Kagan) writes that we need not protest against those who are lenient on this matter.

**Sha'ar Hatziyun 560:8**

> אף דח"א מחמיר גם בזה מ"מ נראה דאין למחות ביד המקילין אחרי שהא"ר הביא
>   בשם האגודה סמך להמקילין שעושין שחור במקום ההוא

Comment: another great answer, thanks! The question is though, what would the Aruch HaShulchan say about our times, where we aren't 'regilin' to do it that way? Does he mean that since everyone does it like that, when you see it you think of the churban? That's the way I understood it...

Comment: @user3148057 It sounds like he's saying that as long as it's recognizable that it is a zecher l'churban it suffices. But it should be noted that the Aruch Hashulchan earlier writes that the whole din doesn't really apply anymore: לפי שידוע שעתה מערבין בהסיד הרבה חול כמעט מחצה על מחצה וא"כ מדין גמור א"צ שיור כלל

Comment: Just want to note that the Shaar HaTziyun that you quote also says to write on it 'zecher l'churban', I'm not sure if its his own chiddush or if he got it from one of the other sources.